# Почему в touch-event есть методы, которые всегда вернут false?

Tags: touch-webkit, gwt, java

А именно методы

- `isAltKeyDown`
- `isControlKeyDown`
- `isMetaKeyDown`
- `isShiftKeyDown`

Если пользователь работает на планшете, они всегда вернут `false`.  Зачем они нужны?

Comment: а не на планшете пользователю нельзя работать?

Comment: Не на планшете будет приходить MouseEvent. А TouchEvent на остальных устройствах просто не поддерживается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что к планшетам, таким как iPad или Motorola Xoom, можно подключить клавиатуру. Так что это сделано не для абстрактной совместимости в будущем, а для вполне реальныx целей в настоящем. Кстати, отлично, что вы задумались об этом сейчас. Так как многие приложения как раз не рассматривают обработку событий в случае, если пользователь подключил клавиатуру к планшету.

Comment: К Acer Iconica A500 (который как и Motorola Xoom работает на андроиде) лично подключал клавиатуру и это все работает (даже половина мультимедийных клавиш).

Answer (score 3):

Чисто теоретически можно допустить, что приход `TouchEvent` может сопровождаться зажатием некоторой клавиши типа `alt`, и с такой точки зрения это решение - скорее нормальный дизайн, чем плохой.

---

Оба `event'a` - `TouchEvent` и `MouseEvent` - наследуются от `HumanInputEvent`, в котором как раз и определены методы типа `isMetaKeyDown()`. И вообще говоря, удобнее обрабатывать весь ввод - будь то `MouseEvent` или `TouchEvent` трактуя их как `HumanInputEvent` - **объединяется схожая функциональность.**

А в том, что в одном из них эти методы возвращают `false` нет ничего страшного - хуже было бы, если бы все эти методы были частью `MouseEvent`, а потом вдруг появился бы девайс, где можно нажимать пальцем и при этом зажимать `alt`. И тут появились бы проблемы - взять и просто безболезненно прокинуть их наверх нельзя, т.к потеряется совместимость с уже написанным кодом.

---

**P.S** Вообще, конкретно в этой ситуации, естественно, что совместимость бы не потерялась, т.к изменения не кардинальные. *Но смысл остается - иногда лучше подумать вперед, чем потом везде пропихивать костыли.*

Answer (score 0):

Как всегда для совместимости и переносимости программ.